# Weighted average within a Summarize function in DAX for Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, summarize, weighted-average

DAX in Power BI

---

Hi all,

I am trying to calculated the weighted average of a specific calculation (sMAPE in my case) for each day in my dataset. I have managed to write a measure that works well for an arithmetic average, see measure below:

```
Simple_SMAPE_BBU_date = AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE(
            summarize(train_output, train_output[item_id] ,train_output[date].[Day]),
            train_output[item_id],
            train_output[date].[Day],
            "SMAPE",
            DIVIDE(
                    ABS(SUM('train_output'[predicted_volume])-SUM(train_output[volume])),
                    SUMX(
                        train_output,
                        abs(train_output[predicted_volume]) + abs(train_output[volume])
                    )
            )
        ),
        [SMAPE]
)
```

However, when I try to write a measure for a weighted average, I can't get it to work. I have tried this measure:

```
VW_SMAPE_BBU_date = sumX(
        SUMMARIZE(
        SUMMARIZE(
            train_output,
            train_output[item_id],
            train_output[date].[Day],
            "SMAPE",
                    DIVIDE(
                    ABS(SUM('train_output'[predicted_volume])-SUM(train_output[volume])),
                    SUMX(
                        train_output,
                        abs(train_output[predicted_volume]) + abs(train_output[volume])
                    )
            )
        ),train_output[item_id],[SMAPE],
        "VW_SMAPE",
        divide(SUM(train_output[volume]),calculate(SUM(train_output[volume]),ALL(train_output[item_id])),0)*
        [SMAPE]
        ),
        [VW_SMAPE]
)
```

The value I get is roughly 3x as big. **So what I want is to calculate the SMAPE for each item for each day, and then do weighted average for each item, based on volume. Does anyone of you superusers have an idea on how to do that?**

Sharing a copiable dummy dataset below:

> 

```html
Category    Subcategory Item ID Date    Predicted volume    Volume
Category 1  Subcategory 1   1   2022-03-14  19.65   18.87
Category 1  Subcategory 1   1   2022-03-15  64.61   65.26
Category 1  Subcategory 1   1   2022-03-16  56.99   54.71
Category 1  Subcategory 1   1   2022-03-17  6.88    7.15
Category 1  Subcategory 1   2   2022-03-14  22.55   21.42
Category 1  Subcategory 1   2   2022-03-15  81.69   84.96
Category 1  Subcategory 1   2   2022-03-16  71.43   70.71
Category 1  Subcategory 1   2   2022-03-17  43.96   42.20
Category 1  Subcategory 1   3   2022-03-14  67.99   66.63
Category 1  Subcategory 1   3   2022-03-15  87.56   91.93
Category 1  Subcategory 1   3   2022-03-16  32.73   34.37
Category 1  Subcategory 1   3   2022-03-17  95.80   92.93
Category 1  Subcategory 1   4   2022-03-14  28.52   28.23
Category 1  Subcategory 1   4   2022-03-15  63.28   64.54
Category 1  Subcategory 1   4   2022-03-16  51.65   52.68
Category 1  Subcategory 1   4   2022-03-17  31.73   33.32
Category 1  Subcategory 1   5   2022-03-14  69.50   66.03
Category 1  Subcategory 1   5   2022-03-15  17.02   17.87
Category 1  Subcategory 1   5   2022-03-16  77.19   80.28
Category 1  Subcategory 1   5   2022-03-17  79.59   82.78
Category 1  Subcategory 2   6   2022-03-14  62.81   64.07
Category 1  Subcategory 2   6   2022-03-15  17.35   17.00
Category 1  Subcategory 2   6   2022-03-16  58.13   60.45
Category 1  Subcategory 2   6   2022-03-17  38.48   38.86
Category 1  Subcategory 2   7   2022-03-14  58.04   58.04
Category 1  Subcategory 2   7   2022-03-15  94.86   99.60
Category 1  Subcategory 2   7   2022-03-16  56.23   57.92
Category 1  Subcategory 2   7   2022-03-17  13.47   12.80
Category 1  Subcategory 2   8   2022-03-14  65.96   62.66
Category 1  Subcategory 2   8   2022-03-15  46.86   48.27
Category 1  Subcategory 2   8   2022-03-16  68.27   65.54
Category 1  Subcategory 2   8   2022-03-17  95.44   93.53
Category 1  Subcategory 2   9   2022-03-14  89.94   89.04
Category 1  Subcategory 2   9   2022-03-15  84.94   80.69
Category 1  Subcategory 2   9   2022-03-16  18.60   18.79
Category 1  Subcategory 2   9   2022-03-17  23.38   23.38
Category 1  Subcategory 2   10  2022-03-14  34.13   34.47
Category 1  Subcategory 2   10  2022-03-15  1.33    1.28
Category 1  Subcategory 2   10  2022-03-16  22.57   21.44
Category 1  Subcategory 2   10  2022-03-17  31.12   31.12
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would be more useful to have a small example dataset together with expected result.

Comment: I don't know if I can provide a dataset. But to give a bit more context you can see the dataset having the following columns: 

- ItemID (a specific SKU we are selling) [string]
- Date Hierarchy (Hierarchy going from Year, Quarter, Month, Date) [Date]
- Volume (Number of items sold for each SKU per day) [value]
- Predicted volume (Numbers of items our model predicted we would sell) [value]
- + more that are not used here.

Will provide the expected result and aim in the next comment (sorry for bad formatting)

Comment: The aim is to assess the strength of the model, which we plan to do using a weighted SMAPE. The expected results is thus a SMAPE calculated per day and item and then when aggregated in different ways (e.g. by several days or for an entire subcategory) the aggregation is based on a weighted average (based on volume).

Comment: Ok, hopefully someone else will pick up on this post who can solve it without a sample dataset.

Comment: Hi again, 

I found a way to share the data, do you mind sending me your email? Or do you know any other ways you recommend sharing data?

Comment: Ah, sorry if you misunderstood. I meant that you create a small, copiable dummy dataset in-post.

Comment: I have added a sample data set above now. Did it as HTML, hope that works! Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: For everyone's info - Solved it!